# Why is SignHash from RSACng (dotNetCore) different from BoncyCastle (running in Mono)?

Tags: mono, x509certificate2

I'm trying summarize: I have a self-signed certificate (created by OpenSSL) being used in a aspnetCore API to verify hash (or message digest, if you prefer) signature. I can run tests to sign the hash and run in the API and everything goes well.

Now, I'm trying do my client sign such hashs and consume the API. It's an application running on Mono. I'm tried do exactly the same thing as my tests, but Mono has a bug in X509Certificate2, when pfx certificate is protected by password. So, I replaced it the by the famous BouncyCastle. However, the results are different... Checking the pk algorithm, I can see some differences, but nothing so remarkable (at least to me).

Can you give me advices? I gonna put the codes:

**Good code running on tests (dotNet Core):**

```
Console.WriteLine("Entry text:");
var text = Console.ReadLine();

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2((byte[])Resource1._2dbb1721_281d_4990_836c_7e46909b8767, "1509a96c-d56b-4e17-af5b-c11f5f214c74");

SHA1Managed sha1Hasher = new SHA1Managed();
UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text);
byte[] hash = sha1Hasher.ComputeHash(data);

RSA provider = (RSA)certificate.PrivateKey;

var signatureData = provider.SignHash(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureData);
```

**Bad code, running on Mono and BouncyCastle:**

```
SHA1Managed sha1Hasher = new SHA1Managed();
var encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(uuid);
byte[] hash = sha1Hasher.ComputeHash(data);

var rsaParameters = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)privateKeyParam);
var provider = RSA.Create();
provider.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

var signatureData = provider.SignHash(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureData);
```

Both certificates are the same. Debugging, I could see the dotNet instantiates on **provider** as **RSACng**. The **SignatureAlgorithm** property is "**RSA**" as the **KeyExchangeAlgorithm** so.

In the **BoncyCastle** over **Mono**, the **provider** is **RSACrytoServiceProvider**. According some articles that I read, this shouldn't make any difference. However, **SignatureAlgorithm** is **"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"**, while **KeyExchangeAlgorithm** is "**RSA-PKCS1-KeyEx**".

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Checking the pk algorithm, I can see some differences` -- what differences? And can you validate your signatures in both cases?

Comment: The differences are those I mentioned, about the provider (specially about the SignatureAlgorithm and the instance of them). About the validation, the dotnet validate perfectly fine and I have test it from that test program. The hash generated in mono not validate in my API dotnet. I didn't check validation in client itself because it were useless, once it didn't got success in validation in against my API.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad: I've just realized my program wasn't using the string it is supposed might use to calculate the hash...

The Mono's version using BouncyCastle is working perfect fine.